# Prove "The principle of induction starting from the base case $n$ ". (Exercise $2.2.7 $ from Tao's Analysis I ).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is a new exercise introduced in the latest ($4$th) edition of the book and thus I haven't found  a proof of this anywhere.

> $\textit{Exercise}$ $2.2.7$. Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to the natural numbers such that whenever $P(m)$ is true, $P(m++)$ is true. Show that if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(m)$ is true for all $m ≥ n$. (This principle is sometimes referred to as the principle of induction starting from the base case $n$.)

Where $n++$ denotes the succesor on $n$. The only Peano Axiom I called upon was his fifth. But here is a full list of everything that we can use  [here](https://imgur.com/a/40Kb1pz).

> Axiom $2.5$. (Principle of mathematical induction). Let $P(n)$ be any property pertaining to a natural number $n$. Suppose that $P(0)$ is true, and suppose that whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(n++)$ is also true. Then $P(n)$ is true for every natural number $n$.

---

I tried something but I can't get it all to work. We assume that $\forall m\left(P(m)\implies P(m++)\right)$. We define "$Q(n):P(n)\implies\forall m\geq n$, $P(m)$" and use induction on $Q$. The base case $n=0$ together with our assumption  tells us that $[P(0)\land (\forall m\left(P(m)\implies P(m++)\right)] \implies \forall m\geq 0$, $P(m)$ which is nothing more than Axiom $2.5$.
Now suppose inductively that $Q(n)$ is true i.e., $P(n)\implies \forall m\geq n$, $P(m)$. We want to show that $P(n++)\implies \forall m\geq n++$, $P(m)$. Assume that $P(n++)$ is true, then by our assumption $P((n++)++)$ is also true. But I need something to use to prove that $P(n)$ is true so that I get $\forall m \geq n, P(m)$. So that I can say $[P((n++)++)\land (\forall m\geq n$, $P(m))]\implies \forall m\geq n++$, $P(m)$ which would complete the induction. But I'm not sure how to get $P(n)$.

Is it valid to assume $P(n)$? Something like $P(n)\implies (P(n++)\implies P((n++)++))\land(\forall m\geq n$, $P(m))]\implies \forall m\geq n++)\implies Q(n++)$ ? I'm not sure if that reasoning makes sense. Or maybe we can use the base case of normal induction?

Comment: If the base case is $n$ , then a successful proof shows that the claim holds for all natural numbers $N\ge n$

Comment: Is it not enough to prove $Q(n)$ by normal induction to prove this? The base case was meant for $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $Q(m) := P(n + m)$. Note that, in particular, $Q(0) = P(n)$.

We are looking to prove the statement "Whenever $P(m)$ is true, $P(m++)$ is true. If $P(n)$ is true, then $P(m)$ is true for $m \geq n$", and we will do so via induction on $Q$.

For the base case, we are already told we can assume $P(n)$ is true, so $Q(0)$ is true.

Then for the inductive step, we have $Q(m) = P(n + m) \implies P((n + m)++) = P(n + (m++)) = Q(m++)$. But since $Q(m) \implies Q(m++)$ and $Q(0)$, then $Q(m)$ is true for every natural $m$.

Now, consider $P(m)$ for $m \geq n$. By the ordering principle, this means that $m = n + a$ for some natural number $a$. That means we can write $P(m) = P(n + a) = Q(a)$, but by our inductive proof $Q(a)$ is true for any natural number $a$, therefore $P(m)$ is also true, and that completes the proof.

If you don't want to use the ordering principle, then an approach like yours applying induction on $n$ is essentially the same thing, but you missed that you are indeed meant to include $P(n)$ in your assumptions.

Comment: This works very nicely. I still see value in seeing how my proof was supposed to work out since I feel like it follows previous hints from the book and thus more people would probably try something closer to it. Does the correct version of my proof follow the logic of my last paragraph?

Comment: I believe so. Like I said, I'm pretty sure they're equivalent at some level.